# Mobilefirst Procedure call blocked by firewall

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm testing the sample app shared by IBM (InvokingAdapterProceduresHybridProject). The firewall recognizes the adapter call as "HTTP Parser Attack" with an error "Check maximum number of header".

I'm unable to proceed further. Please help with inputs.

Comment: Cool, just talking with system engineer or IT department .

Answer (score 0):

Talk with your IT department to allow such calls to pass. This is not related to MobileFirst, and related to your firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Wanted to know if there is a standard or minimum number of HTTP headers to be allowed by firewall for worklight request to pass through.. so i can suggest the IT admins accordingly.